# How to customize HTML structure in ActiveAdmin layout?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, erb

I am trying to change the structure and design of the components of the ActiveAdmin layout, such as the navbar menu, icons and customize it to my style. Is this possible?

I need to overwrite the source code to be able to change the HTML structure, but I have tried to do it by placing files in the / lib folder and I have not succeeded. How could I overwrite the ActiveAdmin source code within my Rails project?

Comment: Why did you place them in the `lib` folder? Rails will first look for view files in the `views` folder of your project, then in the folders of the gems (ActiveAdmin in this case). So, if you place a file your `views` folder that has the identical name and structure to the `ActiveAdmin` view file you want to "override", rails will render your view instead of the `ActiveAdmin` view.

Comment: Yes, that's right. But in this case ActiveAdmin has a peculiar structure in its core, where the views and everything related to its layout is implemented through raw Ruby code, with files that I cannot place directly in the `/views` folder

Comment: Yes, re-defining or patching classes like ActiveAdmin::Views::Pages::Base is required, but see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is *possible* but many developers have discovered it is *not easy*. If you look through the various [plugins](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/wiki/Plugins) you will find examples like [Custom Layout](https://github.com/bys-control/activeadmin_custom_layout), [Sidebar](https://github.com/activeadmin-plugins/active_admin_sidebar), [Menu](https://github.com/yhirano55/active_admin_menu) and [SubNav](https://github.com/zorab47/active_admin-subnav) that may inspire you. However, if you are new to ActiveAdmin and your first priority is to customize the layout heavily then consider [Administrate](https://github.com/thoughtbot/administrate) or vanilla Rails instead: they are still difficult, but you will be fighting the framework less.